# How to change the default frame of the App to a "sub frame"?

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-runtime, mvvm-light

I'm in serious need of help. Working on a WinRT app (Windows 10) with a SplitView. Using MVVMLight (and not Template10) because I've already done a lot of work in standard MVVM to change it now. I've added the SplitView in a separate class named Shell which is how I've seen it done in many different tutorials.

As you may already know, SplitView is basically having a permanent sidebar/pane in the app, while the content pages load within a smaller frame. I can't seem to get my already existing Views to load in the smaller frame of the SplitView. In my Shell.xaml:

```
  <Grid>
    <SplitView x:Name="ShellSplitView" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay"  IsPaneOpen="{Binding PaneOpen}" 
            CompactPaneLength="40" OpenPaneLength="150">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <Grid x:Name="SplitViewPane">
          ...
            </Grid>
        </SplitView.Pane>
        <SplitView.Content>
            <Frame x:Name="ShellViewFrame">                    
            </Frame>
        </SplitView.Content>
    </SplitView>
</Grid>
```

I'm trying to show all my Views within the Frame defined in SpliteView.Content, and having trouble. I'm **not** navigating through the Views, I'm using the MVVM method of NavigationService that comes with MVVM-Light. In my App.xaml.cs I have:

```
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            rootFrame = new Frame();
            rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
            }

            Window.Current.Content = new Shell(rootFrame);    
        } 

        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(Shell), e.Arguments);
        }
```

The MainPage won't even show up within the ShellViewFrame unless I navigate to it in the Shell class code-behind.

So, my question is: Is it possible to make ShellViewFrame the default frame for the NavigationService? Or, instead, can I get a reference to the ShellViewFrame throughout the app so that all Views load within the smaller frame? Or is there a different way to do this altogether?

Comment: There is an INavigationService interface in MVVMLight you could use to write a navigation service to navigate in the frame instead of the whole page.

Comment: There is also a NavigateTo overload that accepts an object parameter.  You could load the whole page and use the parameter to tell the main page which page to load in the ShellViewFrame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to load views in your `SplitView.Content`, for example, if your `SpiltView` is in your `MainPage`, you should use:

```
ShellViewFrame.Navigate(typeof(...));
```

So, if you want to show the `SpiltView` with its `ShellViewFrame`, you can remain to load `MainPage` in your `App.xaml.cs`

```
rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
```

and in your `MainPage()` of `MainPage.xaml.cs`, add this:

```
ShellViewFrame.Navigate(typeof(Shell));
```

Or, second way, you can refer to this [Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlNavigation) in GitHub, this is a better way.

Comment: I checked the GitHub project and their method of using the AppShell, along with @Ken Tucker's solution of creating a new NavigationService solved the issue for me. Thanks guys!